# Access Route Parameters in twig Template

Tags: symfony, routes

How can I access route parameters in a twig template without knowing the name of the parameter/s ?

Answer (score 19):

Route parameters can be accessed in the following way in Twig:

```
{{ app.request.attributes }}
```

You can also use the [`dump()`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) function to see what methods are available:

```
<pre>
{{ dump(app.request.attributes) }}
</pre>
```

Here's a dump of all the parameters:

**Requesting URL**

```
http://example.com/test/3

Route = test
Slug = {param1} = 3
```

**Twig Code**

```
{{ dump(app.request.attributes) }}
```

**Returns**

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)[10]
  protected 'parameters' => 
    array (size=3)
      '_controller' => string 'MyTest\Bundle\Controller\TestController::indexAction' (length=61)
      'param1' => string '3' (length=1)
      '_route' => string 'test' (length=7)
```

Comment: {{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }} just gets the route not the route parameters

Answer (score 16):

You can get all route parameters with:

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route_params') }}
```

if you want just one parameter:

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')['YOUR_PARAMETER_KEY'] }}
```

Comment: Looks like ".get" looks into route params, so following shorter version worked for me 

{{ app.request.attributes.get('paramName') }}

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use the current route with its parameter as a url:

> {{ path(app.request.get('_route'),app.request.get('_route_params')) }}

This can be helpful when you want to eliminate any concatenated strings from the url.

```
app.request.get('_route') gives you the route name from request bag.
app.request.get('_route_params') gives you the route parameters
{{ path(route_name, array of parameters) }} create the path
```